# Timeout exception in a cicle for Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, exception, web-scraping, timeout

I am scraping this page https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/netherlands/eerste-divisie-2018-2019/results/ my code extract all urls of matches and with a cicle `for` will extract data from each urls. (url example https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/netherlands/eerste-divisie-2018-2019/den-bosch-g-a-eagles/YkOxU6sM/) This is my code:

```
for i in matches:
    driver.get(i)

    Country = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/section/ul/li[3]/a"))).text
    leagueseason = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/section/header/h1/a"))).text
    Date = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'match-date'))).text
    Date = Date.replace(".", "/").replace("-", "").replace(" ", "", 1)
    Home = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/section/ul[2]/li[1]/h2/a"))).text
    Away = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/section/ul[2]/li[3]/h2/a"))).text
    ft = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'js-score'))).text
    Res = ""
    
    try:
        extrainfo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='js-eventstage']").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        extrainfo = " "

    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[span]")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[@data-odd])[1]"))).click()
        oid = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[@data-odd])[1]"))).get_attribute("data-oid")
        bid = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[@data-odd])[1]"))).get_attribute("data-bid")
        var = oid+'-'+bid
    except NoSuchElementException:
        B365H = 'no bet365 odd'
    except TypeError:
        B365H = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[@data-odd])[1]"))).get_attribute("data-odd")
    else:
        B365H = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id,'%s')]/tr[last()]/td[@class='bold']" % var))).text

    
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[span]")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[@data-odd])[2]"))).click()
        oid = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[@data-odd])[2]"))).get_attribute("data-oid")
        bid = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[@data-odd])[2]"))).get_attribute("data-bid")
        var = oid+'-'+bid
    except NoSuchElementException:
        B365D = 'no bet365 odd'
    except TypeError:
        B365D = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[@data-odd])[2]"))).get_attribute("data-odd")
    else:
        B365D = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id,'%s')]/tr[last()]/td[@class='bold']" % var))).text


    
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[span]")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[@data-odd])[3]"))).click()
        oid = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[@data-odd])[3]"))).get_attribute("data-oid")
        bid = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[@data-odd])[3]"))).get_attribute("data-bid")
        var = oid+'-'+bid
    except NoSuchElementException:
        B365A = 'no bet365 odd'
    except TypeError:
        B365A = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//td[a[.='bet365']]/following-sibling::td[@data-odd])[3]"))).get_attribute("data-odd")
    else:
        B365A = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id,'%s')]/tr[last()]/td[@class='bold']" % var))).text
```

Now I would add a `TimeoutException` when the page is not loaded and I tried in this way:

```
try:
   #previous code
except TimeoutException:
   driver.get(i)
```

In this way when I meet a Timeout error the code will skip the url scraping and continue with the next url.
How could I fix this problem? I would that in case of Timeout it will reload the page and will scraping data again for that url.

Comment: welcome to SO!! Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: you could but it into a `while` loop that will continue on the same url until it's successful, then move on to the next url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put it into a while loop, that once it successfully completes, will move on. So something like:

```
success = False
while success == False:
    try:
        # previous code
        success = True
    except TimeoutException:
        print ('Will try again...')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this and when there is Timeout it will finish the code

Comment: make sure this is indented within your `for i` loop